# Java modulus operator - why is the result unexpected?

Tags: java, expression, operator-precedence, modulus

I understand that in modulus `17/12 = 5`.

Why `4+17 % 2-1` the value is `4`, and `(4+17) % 2-1` the value is `0`?

Answer (score 6):

Operator precedence. `%` is evaluated first, so

```
4 + 17 % 2 - 1
```

is equivalent to

```
4 + (17 % 2) - 1
```

`17%2 == 1` which yields `4+1-1` which equals `4`

When you place brackets there, you change the order of evaluation:

```
(4+17) % 2 - 1
```

is equivalent to

```
21 % 2 - 1
```

which again, because of `%` having higher precendence than `-`, yields

```
1 - 1
```

which is `0`

Answer (score 0):

`4+17 % 2-1` is interpreted as `4+(17 % 2)-1` = `4 + 1 -1` = `4` (precedence of % operator is higher than `+` and `-`)

`(4+17) % 2-1` = `21 % 2 -1` = `(21 % 2)-1` = `1-1` = `0`